# Image in webpage appear for a short period and then disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many image files in the current directory such as `step_graph0.png,step_graph1.png, step_graph2.png , step_graph3.png` and so on.

My aim to be able to use a single webpage to display them one by one. I created two links, next and previous, and added the `onclick` method to them , so that it change the image.src attribute. The code is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload =function f()  {

    f.me  = f.me || 0;

    //alert(f.me);

    var p =document.getElementById("previous");
    var n =document.getElementById("next");
    var image = document.getElementById("graph");

    alert(f.me);

    p.onclick = function(){
        f.me = f.me|| 0;
        if( f.me >  0 ) f.me--;
        image.src = "step_graph"+(parseInt(f.me) ) + ".png";


        //window.location.reload();
    }

    n.onclick = function(){
        f.me = ++f.me || 0;
        image.src = "step_graph"+(parseInt(f.me) )+".png";


        //window.location.reload();
    }


    }       

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="previous" href="">step_back</a> <a id="next" href="">step_forward</a><br>
        <center>
        <img id="graph" src ="step_graph1.png" ></img></center>
        code<br>
        output<br>

    </body>
</html>
```

I save this file as index.html in the same directory as the images. Initally, it shows the image. But when I click next and previous links, it shows the desired image, but within milliseconds, it just goes back to the original image. I am using f.me as a static variable to save the image file index, such as `0,  1 , 2 , 3` in filenames `step_graph0.png, step_graph1.png, step_graph2.png` etc.

I tried it for an hour. and I think it's about `window.onload` function resetting everything. But that's just a wild guess to satisfy myself.

I anybody can find out the mistake in the code, please do so.

Comment: any errors thrown? Should be throwing an error that `f` is undefined

Comment: @charlietfl where to look for them,( firefox web developer console showing none )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    var me = me || 0;

     //alert(f.me);

    var p = document.getElementById("previous");
    var n = document.getElementById("next");
    var image = document.getElementById("graph");



    $('#previous').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#try').html('prev');
      e.preventDefault();
      me = me || 0;
      if (me > 0) me--;
      image.src = "http://home.iitk.ac.in/~amitkum/images/" + (parseInt(me)) + ".jpg";
      //window.location.reload();
    });

    n.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      me = ++me || 0;
      image.src = "http://home.iitk.ac.in/~amitkum/images/" + (parseInt(me)) + ".jpg";


      //window.location.reload();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body> <a id="previous" href="#">step_back</a>  <a id="next" href="#">step_forward</a>

  <br>
  <br>
  <img id="graph" src="http://home.iitk.ac.in/~amitkum/images/2.jpg" height="100"></img>
  <div id="try">jk</div>
```

Comment: That means all I needed was a preventDefault() :). Thanks Amit. It worked.

Comment: You can actually remove preventDefault() as href="#"
but you were using f.me where f was not defined.

Comment: Okay,so that's why. Did not know that.